# How to redefine the \today with superscript?

Tags: xetex, superscripts, datetime, isodate, date

How can I redefine `\today` so that today's current date comes in the format

```
May 26th, 2016
```

I need the "th" to be superscript.

It should come to the bottom right corner of the page. The code does not work when I use it in the following environment XeLaTeX.

```
%  Preamble:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass{article}
\usepackage[head=12pt, foot=12pt, top=18mm, bottom=15mm, left=12.7mm, right=12.7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup{ord=raise}
\usepackage{rotating}

%  Main Tex:

\begin{document}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{5mm} 
\begin{textblock}{60}(205,207)
\begin{turn}{90} 
Last Updated on
\today
\end{turn}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

I need this to come as [Last Updated on May 26th, 2016]. "th / st /nd " raised to superscript height. Rotated 90 Deg. Bottom Right Corner of page. Please Check MWE Link Below.

Also I Keep getting this Warning:

```
Package datetime2 Warning: Region `english-base' has ignored (datetime2) the following settings: (datetime2) ord=raise on input line 13.
```

Link to MWE: 
https://www.overleaf.com/5308800stsrzk#/16764374/

Comment: This question, at least to me, is very very unclear. Are you talking about the one occasion on the title where you do `\date{May 26th, 2016}` or are you using a package for formatting the date. Please elaborate.

Comment: Your new example isn't compilable as is. For sure, replace `\LoadClass` with `\documentclass`. More importantly: Where and how is `\turn` defined?

Comment: \turn is defined in package rotating. i missed out. apologies

Comment: The warning is because you've omitted the optional argument of `\DTMlangsetup`, so it's trying to apply the setting to all loaded modules, but the base module doesn't recognise the setting. So just do `\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}` to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you use the [datetime2](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2) package with the option `en-US`:

[image]

The instruction `\DTMlangsetup{ord=raise}` instructs `datetime2` to treat the day number as an ordinal and to raise the `st`/`nd`/`rd` particles to superscript height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup{ord=raise}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's augmented question: It looks like you're using `UKenglish` as the main language option for `babel`, yet also wanting a US-style date string ("May 26th, 2016" -- with "th" raised) rather than a UK-style date string ("26th May 2016" -- "th" not raised). To achieve this objective, you need to (a) provide "USenglish" as a secondary language option when loading `babel` and (b) execute the instruction `\selectlanguage{USenglish}` inside the `textblock` environment.

The code shown below should compile equally well under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[head=12pt,foot=12pt,top=18mm,bottom=15mm,hmargin=12.7mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}    
\usepackage[USenglish,UKenglish]{babel}   
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{ord=raise}    
\usepackage{rotating} % provides \turn macro

\begin{document}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{5mm} 

\begin{textblock}{60}(205,207)
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\begin{turn}{90} 
Last Updated on \today
\end{turn}
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yay! worked like a charm.
Thanks for providing the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Note: If you are trying to use superscript format using british date order you need to remove `british` from `\documentclass[british]{article}` (as was my document). I have no idea why and I also cannot find a reference for what setting `british` does nor how it overrides everything else.

Comment: @Annan - It would help if you provided a bit more information about your document setup. E.g., do you use the `babel` package?

Comment: @Mico Hmm, so with `\documentclass[british]{article}` and `\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}` it causes problems. With *all* other combinations, or removing one parameter, it works fine. If neither are specified it fails compilation. It also works when not using `babel`. What really confuses me is why other combinations don't have the same behaviour. I would expect one of the options to override the other, or for one to have higher priority.

Comment: @Annan - I’m afraid your reply wasn’t exactly illuminating. I suggest you post a *new* query, in which you provide full details of your document setup and what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico I was trying to achieve exactly what the original question is asking however I wanted the british date ordering. While applying your answer to my own document I ran into an inconsistency which took a while to fix. I fixed my own problem by removing `[british]` and I thought I should post a note so anyone in the future who reads this and cannot get it working has something to try.